# create-react-native-app app-name doesn't work as it should

Tags: node.js, react-native

I am new to react native. I have created an application before and it worked fine. Now I created another application and noticed that in cmd it doesn't look the same as before as shown in image. Moreover after running **npm run eject**, it doesn't create an index.js file but gives the message of ejected successfully. [(Console Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DL6i.png)

Comment: Can you describe exactly what looks different or seems to be missing? There isn't a lot of info to go by!

Comment: I tried to run command **npm run android** and it gave me error in console log

:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
also it cannot find
ReactApplication and ReactNativeHost

Comment: That's after ejecting, I assume?

Comment: Yes. After ejecting

Comment: Did you install dependencies? (running `npm install` or `yarn`)

Comment: Result of npm install:
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.3 (node_modules\sane\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN eslint-plugin-react-native@3.3.0 requires a peer of eslint@^3.17.0 || ^4 || ^5 but none was installed.

Comment: I don't think that should affect your project.
Give it another shot at running on your mobile phone

Comment: I have tried more than 5 to 10 times. I even created new project just to check but all in vain..